# Facebook user profile picture

Tags: facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Publishing a post on users' wall by facebook app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013226/publishing-a-post-on-users-wall-by-facebook-app)

I need to generate a picture from facebook user profile picture and post it to some users' walls. For instance, $attch = array( 'media' => array((array('type' => 'image', 'src' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture',
'href' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture/')));

'src' => 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$uid.'/picture' line doesn't show any picture...

How can I resolve this?